# Page shifted up in Safari but not other browsers

Tags: css, safari

My website http://www.rattletree.com/ works fine in other browsers, and used to work correctly in Safari, but I just noticed that the navigation elements are shifted up now.  Can anyone recommend what needs to change in the css?  Thanks!

I usually use firefox with firebug, but I'm not able to figure out how to use the dev tools in Safari to test css changes, so I'm chasing my tail here...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603883/negative-margin-different-result-on-safari-than-any-other-browser

Comment: Indeed-it looks like a similar problem.  There wasn't an accepted answer, and the one with the upvote suggested using display:block; which is already in the css...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that safari experiences problems whenever there is a negative margin greater than the size of the element in the relevant dimension ( height or width ).

The contents of `.abovenavcontainer` are all floated, with no clearfix, or float clear applied, so it has a height of zero, so the negative margin size ( 69 ) is greater than 0. Try adding a clearfix, or laying out the child elements without float, like, say, `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Looks like that worked in IE, FF, Safari, and Chrome.  Thank you!