# Css-styles safari issue (mac os)

Tags: html, css

Can't find right values for styling menu here: http://demo.imatte.us/fomru/landingpage.html

Screen: i.imgur.com/iCBbIpP.png

- just in safari, mac os.

Also, have another problem. When I'm choosing some element in first dropdown menu, then all panel bouncing some time. Think that's because 1 element in this menu has one style, and all other elements has another styles.

Screen: i.imgur.com/Bk5mbpF.png

Please, somebody, help me to find right css styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the issue with the first dropdown menu: it's bouncing because the height of `.filter-elements .element-all` is 2 px less than for the other images. I've just changed the height from 22px to 24px and it doesn't bounce anymore. Because the image would be scaled inapproriate then, I'd suggest just to increase the margin-bottom by 2px:

```
.filter-elements .element-all
{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e41b47;
  box-shadow: 7px 8px #9bb3c8, 16px 0 #0c66bb, 7px -8px #85b560;
  height: 22px;
  margin: 8px 18px 8px 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
  width: 22px;
}
```

changed into

```
.filter-elements .element-all
{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e41b47;
  box-shadow: 7px 8px #9bb3c8, 16px 0 #0c66bb, 7px -8px #85b560;
  height: 22px;
  margin: 8px 18px 10px 5px;  // <-- increased margin here
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
  width: 22px;
}
```

For the issue with Mac Safari - as I don't have a Mac here I can't test properly, but I guess it's an issue with the negative margin that's been set. There have been some known problems with Safari (don't know if they're already fixed) for elements having position: relative and a negative margin - [Stackoverflow: Negative margin has different results on Mac Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603883/negative-margin-different-result-on-safari-than-any-other-browser). You could try if changing the `position:absolute` for `.filters .filter-name:after` into `position:relative` would solve the Safari problem with the vertical alignment, but then you would have to take care about some follow up css-adjustments as this will affect the horizontal positioning.